# Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, map, iteradores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy creando un método que recorra una `map` y cuando se encuentre un valor del `map` que es 0, pues ese elemento se borra del `map`.

```java
    //Declaración del map en el constructor de esa misma clase 
    private Map<String,Integer> libroVisitas = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
      public LagoSagrado(){
        libroVisitas = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
      }
    //Declaración del método 
    public void purgar(){

    Iterator it = libroVisitas.keySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      Object key = it.next();
      if(libroVisitas.get(key) == 0){
        libroVisitas.remove(key);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: No se puede eliminar el elemento mientras recorres la lista. La interfaz Iterator tiene un método llamado [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--), en la cual, permite eliminar el elemento de forma segura.